# Resizing street view object

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, flash, google-street-view

Hello StackOverflow'ers, 
I have a (flex) app that, on the click of a button, resize a div (in javascript) at the bottom of the page and shows your position in google street view in it.

The things is that if I open the browser at 80% of width, click on the button and then maximize the window, the div won't take 100% of width. I have a function that his being called 'onResize' on the body tag of the page, but it doesn't seems to work. Here is the code :

```
...

function handleResize()
{
 document.getElementById('streetviewDiv').style.width='100%';
}

...

<body onResize="handleResize()">
```

How can I achieve the auto-resize of the street view? There must be a specific id for that object so that we could get it by javascript, but I haven't found it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to show some of the markup and CSS. There could be any number of reasons why you're not getting a resize. Normal DIV behavior is, absent any width setting, to expand horizontally to fill the parent container. So either your div is being constrained by a parent element or something else weird is going on.

It could also so happen that the div is expanding but its visible contents is not, if your StreetView object is what you expect to expand but doesn't.

Comment: If I'm correct, google street view is a flash object that is being inserted in my div 'streetviewDiv', so it's probably this object that I need to resize, not the div.

Comment: Then you should probably see if the <embed> markup for the Flash movie has a hard-coded width.

Comment: Using javascript:alert(document.getElementById('streetviewDiv').innerHTML) I found the id of the flash object (panoflash1). In the onResize() function I simply add document.getElementById('panoflash1').width='100%'.

Answer (score 3):

The following works for me.  You need to include jQuery-UI.

```
$("#streetViewDivId").resizable({handles: 'n,w,s,e', minWidth: 200, maxWidth: 600});    

$("#streetViewDivId").on( "resizestop", function( event, ui ) {

    google.maps.event.trigger(panorama, 'resize');

    console.log('streetview resize ended');
});
```

Comment: In my Angular project the street view panorama only filled a section of the div after the div was resized from code. The triggering of the event solved it for me. I read up on the resize event in the google help files and they explicitly state that the resize event must be triggered after the containing div is resized: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/street-view#StreetViewPanorama.resize

Comment: This solved my problem. My street view was black at first and then visible after window resize

Answer (score 0):

I think its's pure Javascript as of v3 of the api.

this helped me:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewPanorama

resize  None    Developers should trigger this event on the panorama when its div changes size: google.maps.event.trigger(panorama, 'resize').